# Can klove reporter (Extent Report) be customized using Config.xml file?

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Can we use Config.xml to customize klov reporter ? I was trying this out using below code, but i don't see it working. Please take a look and let me know if i'm doing any thing wrong here.

```
        var klovReporter = new KlovReporter();

        klovReporter.LoadConfig(configFilePath);

        // specify mongoDb connection
        klovReporter.InitMongoDbConnection("192.168.28.88", 27017);

        // specify project ! you must specify a project, other a "Default project will be used"
        klovReporter.ProjectName = "CsharpReports";

        // you must specify a reportName otherwise a default timestamp will be used
        klovReporter.ReportName = "Build " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

        // URL of the KLOV server
        klovReporter.KlovUrl = "192.168.28.88:8090";

        _extent = new ExtentReports();
        _extent.AttachReporter(klovReporter);
```

I am using the below xml file for the custom configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<extentreports>
  <configuration>
    <!-- report theme -->
    <!-- standard, dark -->
    <theme>dark</theme>

    <!-- document encoding -->
    <!-- defaults to UTF-8 -->
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

    <!-- protocol for script and stylesheets -->
    <!-- defaults to https -->
    <protocol>https</protocol>

    <!-- title of the document -->
    <documentTitle>Automation Test Report</documentTitle>

    <!-- report name - displayed at top-nav -->
    <reportName>Automation Test Report</reportName>

    <!-- location of charts in the test view -->
    <!-- top, bottom -->
    <testViewChartLocation>bottom</testViewChartLocation>

    <!-- custom javascript -->
    <scripts>
      <![CDATA[

       ]]>
    </scripts>
  </configuration>
</extentreports>
```

I would also be interested to know the type of views available in klov reporter(Community version). As i could see some of the views are missing in my report which are there in the [demo klov](http://klov.herokuapp.com/dashboard) reporter. Please take a look into the below reports for better understanding.

**Available views in my klov report:**

[image]

**Views available in klov reporter demo.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  To make any changes to Klov, you will have to modify the sources directly.  The version you have share is 0.1.0 which is available now.  Some of the elements are not available to the community version API which is why the Tags link is not visible.

Comment: Thanks you @Anshoo , I tried modifying klov source and it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

what you meant by changing the source?

Comment: You can clone the Klove repository available in github, make desired changes and build the servlet jar. You may also like to add your query as a comment, and not as answer.